# What are the design reasons to forbid accessing static elements of the class via object

Tags: c#, oop, static

I cannot emphasis this more -- **design reasons**.

In C++ you could get static element using class (type) reference or object (instance) reference. In C# only the type reference. The more I write in C# the more problems it causes -- there are simply moments (again and again) that all I have is object, and in order to to avoid problem with lack of type (and thus access to static element) by creating regular element which passess values back and forth to static element.

One can say, that creating regular (non-static) element within a class to work as proxy for static element is small price, but I don't get for what actually I am paying. The burden is obvious for me, not critical, but annoying, so what are the benefits?

What are the design reasons, in C# you cannot reference static element of the object (from outside of course)?

#### Code sample

```
public class Foo
{
   public static readonly string Name = "name";
}

...

Foo foo = new Foo();
```

and now consider "Foo.Name" against "foo.Name";

#### Example of real case

One of the most used class for me is associative array (my custom class) for enums -- AssocEnum. It is like Dictionary but all keys are prefilled. On top of it I have classes like EnumBit (which is AssocEnum) and EnumNames (which is AssocEnum). Unlike Dictionary every instance of give enum has the same Keys property. Which means you could get Keys for AssocEnum type and for its instance.

What bothers me is the fact I have to introduce two properties TypeKeys (for class) and Keys (for instance--which is just a proxy of TypeKeys) just because I cannot call static TypeKeys for instance of AssocEnum.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. If the *static* type of an expression is `object`, how would the compiler know what class the `static` member you want to access is defined in? The same limitation exists in C++, although it's not as readily obvious because there is no `object` base class. Can you post some code for what you are trying to do?

Comment: In C++, you surely can't do that unless the compiler knows the type?

Comment: @macias please provide some sample code of what you're doing

Comment: **Tigran**, done; **Marc Gravell**, for compiler the code is obviously known, but for me -- either not or it is too elaborate to be handy, like "Dictionary<int,List<string>>". **Jon**, by "object" I mean "instance of the class" (i.e. object) not the "Object type/class". In C++ there is no such limitation.

Comment: Re the edit; `Foo.Name` seems perfectly correct; `foo.Name` - not so much; it isn't the name of any particular `foo`. Re the inconvenient `Dictionary<int,List<string>>` - a bit of a contrived example, but you could use an `using` alias to make it less verbose.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, ad.Name) exactly, like static names for properties to send/get notifications, it is the same name for any foo, so it would be good to be valid, ad.using) sure (in some cases), but it is exactly the burder I am talking about

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMO the "design reason" here is, in part, related to making intent obvious. Here's a classic example:

```
Thread someOtherThread = GetAnotherThread();
someOtherThread.Sleep();
```

now; which thread just went to sleep? `Thread.Sleep()` is a static method; it only ever impacts the *current* thread. But our code has suggested (quite incorrectly) that we called a method relating to a specific instance (`someOtherThread`).

It would have been entirely possible to design the language to *allow* it to resolve static methods; that is trivial - so it is absolutely an intentional design choice, rather than a technical limitation.

As another example:

```
Control someControl = GetSomeRandomControl();
someControl.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

our code *suggests* we have made a change to disable cross-thread checks *for a specific object*; but that is incorrect. We have actually impacted ***all*** controls, since `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is a static member.

Thus:

```
Thread.Sleep():
```

and:

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

are far clearer in terms of expressing what they do.

Comment: I think that such approach is wrong -- you assume you have the library before you even have the language. Please note that language affects all aspects of using it. To make your objection valid you should rather show that you cannot write a library with ability to call static elements from anywhere, because now you are comparing _current_ C# library with _current_ C++ language. Of course it won't work because authors of C# library assumed C#, not C++.

Comment: @macias I honestly don't understand the point you are trying to make there. In .NET the languages and library *are* separate, and it would be entirely possible to write a CLI language that allowed you to call static members from a type instance. I didn't compare anything to C++; simply, given that a choice had to be made ("do we allow this, or not?"), I'm content that the choice they *did* make was for good and clear reasons.

Comment: @macias also, if it is causing you pain, you can almost certainly get around it with extension methods

Comment: "and it would be entirely possible to write a CLI language that allowed you to call static members from a type instance". And this was my point (I refered to C++, because it lets you do this). I understand that you are comfy, but still there are no reasons for language design given -- Sleep could be removed, and ThisThread (singleton) with SleepThis introduced. Thank you very much for remark about ext. methods, you cannot use it in all cases (they are just methods) but in my CURRENT case this will be perfect.

Comment: @macias look at another way: what wwould be the justification/reason for *including* this in the language?

Comment: The fundamental point Marc's example implies is true even if you kill sleep: Calling a static element of a class via object incorrectly implies that the class instance has some bearing on the call.  You could try to design libraries to prevent such confusion, but I fail to see any meaningful benefits to allowing access to static elements of a class via object.

Comment: @**Brian** and **Marc**, I already wrote about problems--sometimes all you have is object, not a type. In order to call anything static you have to provide non-static proxy to get static element. It is a lot of burden, because you have to duplicate a lot of functionality. "Calling a static element of a class via object incorrectly implies that the class instance has some bearing on the call" this applies to calls inside this object too, and somehow nobody has problem with it. You also imply that some "property" of class makes no sense when related to instance, this is not true in general.

Comment: @Macias: Can you provide an example situation where you end up needing to create such a proxy?

Comment: @Brian, added (sorry for the delay, I didn't get any notification).

Comment: When this issue was resurrected for me, I found my own old question :-) However today I am in control (of my own language) and I see the problem here. So thank you once again (+1), I simply revert the syntax of the C++ and this will make things clear.

Answer (score 1):

The static access via type definition only, in my opinion, gives an idea to caller of "stateless" call (Sure it's not always true, cause you can change other static  variables).